# Cannot install poco-devel on CentOS 7.5

Tags: centos, centos-7

I am trying to install poco libraries with:

```
yum install poco-devel*
```

But I have the following errors:

```
Package poco-pagecompiler-1.6.1-3.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by nspoco-1.6.0-el6.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: poco-devel-1.6.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: poco-pagecompiler(x86-64) = 1.6.1-3.el7
           Available: poco-pagecompiler-1.6.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               poco-pagecompiler(x86-64) = 1.6.1-3.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

When I try to compile the application, I have the following cmake error:

```
-- Looking for POCO...
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.27.1") 
-- Checking for module 'POCO'
--   No package 'POCO' found
```

How do I resolve this error ?

Comment: You are trying to install an obsolete package (poco-pagecompiler) for which latest package (nspoco) is already installed. See the first line in the errors.

Comment: But how to avoid installing this poco-pagecompiler ?

Comment: You don't need to. Latest package ( that can avoid obsolete packages as in your case ) `nspoco` is already installed. Have a look at first line in the errors.

Comment: Ok. But I am not sure poco is well installed on my system cause I still have this error "package 'POCO' not found" when I try to compile a project.

Comment: In that case, something else is the problem. Try to cross-check for package being installed by `yum list poco-devel*` and `yum info poco-devel`.

Comment: I think there is no difference. `yum list poco-devel*` gives me `poco-devel.x86_64 1.6.1-3.el7 epel` and `yum info poco-devel` gives me `Arch : x86_64 Version : 1.6.1 Release : 3.el7`

Comment: So, you have the package already installed. In that case something else is the problem. Please paste error outputs while compiling the project.

Comment: I updated question with the error.

Comment: Why is `nspoco` installed in the first place?

Comment: I don't know. I tried to remove it but I still have the problem...